# Using bcp with filename taken from another column

Tags: sql-server, bcp

Using `bcp`, I want to save all `.docx` files based on contents stored in a column (`content`) of a table `T` in SQL Server.

```
|--|-------|
|id|content|
|--|-------|
|12|0xraert|
|13|0xrteot|
|14|0xrtezt|
|15|0xrteta|
|..| ...   |
```

A working request, for one document (that has `id=13`), is the following:

```
bcp "SELECT content FROM T WHERE id = 13" \
queryout "output\path\13.docx" \
-S xxx  \
-d xxx  \
-T \
-C \
RAW  \
< path\to\parameters.txt
```

How can I make a query such that all contents go saved to `{id}.docx`? I can make a shell loop with random indices but I'd want filenames to match exactly `id` columns...

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BCP will only create a single file per execution of BCP. To do what you are asking would require something similar to what you stated. A separate process to build and execute a BCP statement for each file you want to create. This cannot be done in a single query and execution of BCP.

Comment: Thanks a lot @jamie for your answer. Do you happen to have any reference for this statement? That would make it even stronger. I found a workaround by first collecting all the IDs, and then iterating over them with one `bcp` command for each.

Comment: Sure! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver15